# Can you set the value of an excel control with EPPLUS?

Tags: excel, epplus

Is it possible to set the value of an excel control, for example a textbox or a radio button, with the EPPLUS-library?

We have an excel document that will be used as a template to create other excel files. With EPPLUS you can easily load the template, fill in cell values and save it as a new document like:

```
var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Template.xlsm"));
excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["B11"].Value = "Hello!";
excelPackage.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\NewDocument.xlsm"));
```

However, the excel template also contains textboxes and radiobuttons that we need to assign values to before saving.

We have previously used a non-free library called Spire.XLS to do this, but it's  kind of overkill just to do this. Plus it would be nice to not have to deal with license files and such.

We also like to avoid the interop-library since you have to install office on the deployment server.

EPPLUS is a really nice library so if it is possible to use that to do this it would be really nice. If it doesn't support controls, would it be hard to extend it to support this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand so please correct me, you want to save your excel file as a template so that next time when you open a file based on this template all the values are filled by defaults. More precisely, you would like that the by default the radiobuttons and texboxes have the same values as the original file?

Comment: No, the template should never be changed and the radios and textboxes are all empty in the template (not filled out). I only want to make filled out copies of the template. One solution would be to code the entire excel file from scratch with values and all, but the thing is that the template is a customer document that will be updated from time to time. So to avoid code changes every time the template changes (if it's layout changes or such) it is better to use their document as template and only supply the values for specific fields.

Comment: You can loop over all the controls of a spreadsheet "for each ctrl in worksheet(name),controls", then give them a value "ctrl.value ='world' ". Additionally, in your loop, you can put if statements to make sure that only the proper controls are given a value.

Comment: ok. Hmm, I can't find any property "Controls" in ExcelWorksheets. Are we still talking about EPPlus here? Or is some other library?

Comment: There is a property "WorksheetXml" which seems to be the xml representation of the sheet. The xml contains a section "controls", but there is only one control. There should be several. Maybe the textboxes isn't controls but som other excel entity. The textboxes looks like grey resizeable and movable boxes where the user can input text.